# nodejs-convert json object to string array in $.get response

Tags: jquery, json, node.js

Now I am trying to return array of strings with the response to a $.get() request , so I converted the string array to JSON object

```
var messagesFromFile = Array();
    messagesFromFile[0]="code";
    messagesFromFile[1]="eat";
    messagesFromFile[2]="play";
    messagesFromFile[3]="sleep";
    response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'application/json'})
    response.write(JSON.stringify(messagesFromFile));
    response.end();
```

, then in the front end ,I wanted to convert the json object back to string array

```
$(window).load(function(){
            $.get("http://localhost:8000",
                {
                    name:"GetAllMessages"
                },function(data,status){
                    try{
                        var arr = $.parseJSON(data);
                    }
                    catch(err){
                        alert(err);
                    }
                });
        });
```

but an "syntax error unexpected token" exception is thrown !!! any help to overcome this exception or any way to return array of strings with the response 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally jQuery will already have parsed the JSON for you, especially if the content type header is set correctly. My guess is that you're trying to decode an already decoded object. Try putting `console.log("GET results: type: %s data: %s", typeof data, data)` before the `$.parseJSON` call.

Comment: the type of data is object ,then I used toString() method then split() method to get the array of strings , Thanks Mr Jessie for your reply

Comment: If the type of `data` is an object, it's probably already an array. So you're doing `Array -> JSON -> Array -> Comma Separated String -> Array`. You can remove the last two steps. I'm 98% sure it's already the array you're looking for.